# How to run Logistic Regression in Scala for Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I have read the data file as below:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("D:/ModelData.csv")


+---------+---------+---+-----+-------+
|c1       |    c2   |c3 |  c4 |  c5   |
+---------+---------+---+-----+-------+
|        1|        1| 13|  100|      1|
|        1|        1| 13|  200|      0|
|        1|        1| 13|  300|      0|
+---------+---------+---+-----+-------+
```

So Then My input to the model are c5 and c4.(c1,c2,c3 are same for all the rows)

```
val df3=df.select("c5", "c4")

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(10)
      .setRegParam(0.3)
      .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val lrModel = lr.fit(df3)

val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
println(trainingSummary)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.It does not print anything.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Given the `dataframe` as

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|c1 |2  |c3 |c4 |c5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |1  |13 |100|1  |
|1  |1  |13 |200|0  |
|1  |1  |13 |300|0  |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The question suggests that `c4` and `c5` is to be used for `LogisticRegression` (`c4` and `c5` as `features` and `c5` as `label`)

`features` vector `column` of `doubles` can be formed using `VectorAssembler` as

```
val assembler =  new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("c4"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
```

`label` and `features` columns are required for `LogisticRegression` so

```
val df3 = assembler.transform(df).select($"c5".cast(DoubleType).as("label"), $"features")
```

which is

```
+-----+--------+
|label|features|
+-----+--------+
|1.0  |[100.0] |
|0.0  |[200.0] |
|0.0  |[300.0] |
+-----+--------+
```

Now `LogisticRegression` can be applied as

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val lrModel = lr.fit(df3)

val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
println(trainingSummary)
```

Output is

```
org.apache.spark.ml.classification.BinaryLogisticRegressionTrainingSummary@6e9f8160
```

Comment: Why do you use the label as a feature? The purpose of supervised modelling is to determine the label. Using it as a feature makes no sense to me.

Comment: This was just an example to help you understand the flow :) you can use other values for features other than label.

Comment: @Rumo I have updated my answer . :) Now it should be fine. isn't it?

Comment: @Rumo if the answer is fine then please remove your downvote :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your classifier needs to know what to learn. Therefore, you have to define the label column and the feature column for your classifier.

The default name for the feature column is "features" and the default name for the label column is "label".

You can either rename your columns to "label" and "features":

```
lr.fit(df3.withColumnRenamed("c4","features").withColumnRenamed("c5","label"))
```

Or you can define which column to use as the feature/label column:

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
  .setLabelColumn("c5")
  .setFeaturesColumn("c4")
```